# Difference between the two Flatpak backends available in apt for Plasma Discover? Is there a problem from Installing both?

Tags: apt, kde, plasma, flatpak, discover-software-center

So basically I wanted to add Flatpak support to Discover and I came up with these two different Apt commands

```
sudo apt install plasma-discover-flatpak-backend

sudo apt install plasma-discover-backend-flatpak
```

They appear to be two different packages with very similar name
I decided to install both just to be sure, but I don't know if that's going to cause an issue down the line or something

Could anyone explain the difference between the two and if its OK if I installed them both?

(And if installing them both is an issue which one should I keep?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** on modern systems 21.04, 21.10 and upcoming 22.04 LTS you have to use `plasma-discover-backend-flatpak` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/plasma-discover-backend-flatpak), on older 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS systems it will be installed by transitional [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/plasma-discover-flatpak-backend) named `plasma-discover-flatpak-backend` as dependency.

According to the search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=plasma-discover+flatpak+backend&searchon=names) both two packages exist with the following relations and properties:

- `plasma-discover-flatpak-backend` exists only in 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS.

  In 18.04 LTS is [provides](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/plasma-discover-flatpak-backend) Flatpak [functionality](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/plasma-discover) to Discover.
  In 20.04 LTS it [depends](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/plasma-discover-flatpak-backend) on [`plasma-discover-backend-flatpak`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/plasma-discover-flatpak-backend), the latter provides Flatpak functionality to Discover. For 20.04 LTS `plasma-discover-flatpak-backend` is marked as [transitional package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/plasma-discover).
- `plasma-discover-backend-flatpak` exists in all modern Ubuntu releases like 20.04 LTS, 21.04, 21.10 and upcoming 22.04 LTS.

  This package provides Flatpak functionality to Discover.

Comment: So if I read this correctly, installing the old one in 20.04 (the one I'm using) basically just tells the system to get the new one instead. So even tho I have those 2 separate packages installed, one of them is just like a redirect to the new one, so there shouldn't be any problem in my system right?

Answer (score -2):

So, according to [this](https://flatpak.org/setup/Kubuntu/) post, you're installing packages for versions 18.04 <> 20.04.

 Google search is a good friend, if you use too =) !